# How to make results of "localedef" survive "dpkg-reconfigure locales"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, localization

Im using UB 16.04 LTS Server and yesterday a new version of the [locales](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/locales)-package has been released and installed:

```
Start-Date: 2019-02-21  09:44:05
Commandline: /usr/bin/apt-get -y -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confdef -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confold dist-upgrade
Upgrade: [...], locales:amd64 (2.23-0ubuntu10, 2.23-0ubuntu11), [...]
End-Date: 2019-02-21  09:44:45
```

I'm additionally using PostgreSQL 11 with databases relying on the character set `windows-1252` for historical reasons:

```
Name  |  Owner   | Encoding |   Collate    |    Ctype     |   Access[...]
------+----------+----------+--------------+--------------+--------------
[...] | postgres | WIN1252  | de_DE.CP1252 | de_DE.CP1252 |
```

To make that available, the following command is used:

```
localedef -f CP1252 -i /usr/share/i18n/locales/de_DE /usr/lib/locale/de_DE.CP1252
```

Using `locale-gen` before/after `localedef` gives the following error:

```
locale-gen de_DE.CP1252
Error: 'de_DE.CP1252' is not a supported language or locale
```

That error message is correct, the file `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` doesn't contain my locale. From my understanding that's why I need to use `localedef`.

The problem now is that most likely after the new `locales`-package has been installed, my manually added one was removed automatically and access to the databases relying on that locale failed:

```
2019-02-21 09:42:45.109 CET [27039] FATAL:  Datenbank-Locale ist inkompatibel mit Betriebssystem
2019-02-21 09:42:45.109 CET [27039] DETAIL:  Die Datenbank wurde mit LC_COLLATE »de_DE.CP1252« initialisiert, was von setlocale() nicht erkannt wird.
```

From my understanding, all locales which were recognized and enabled by `dpkg-reconfigure locales` have been kept and my custom locale was not listed there. So I followed instructions from `/etc/locale.gen` and created the following file with the following line:

```
/usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED
de_DE.CP1252 CP1252
```

That made my locale available in the end:

[image]

The problem is that this doesn't seem to be enough to solve my goal: Whenever I run `dpkg-reconfigure locales`, the created locale using `localedef` gets deleted from the folder `/usr/lib/locale/de_DE.CP1252` and Postgres fails again. Even though `locale -a` prints my locale and such. So that's most likely what was happening with/after installing the new `locales`-package. If I run `localedef` like documented above manually again, Postgres instantly allows access to the legacy databases again.

One interesting thing I recognized is the locale `C.UTF-8` being available in `/usr/lib/locale` like my custom one, BUT that never gets deleted automatically for some reason. Searching for that locale in the web, it seems it is provided as part of some package by the distribution instead of configured and generated locally as needed:

> We now have an "uninstallable" C.UTF-8 locale that is available even if you delete locale-archive, or change the installed language set for locale-archive.

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=902094#c20

```
/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_ADDRESS
/usr/lib/locale/C.UTF-8/LC_COLLATE
```

https://packages.debian.org/de/sid/sh4/libc-bin/filelist

So, what do I need to do to make my `localedef`-results survive `dpkg-reconfigure locales` or whatever has been done during installing the new `locales`-packages`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different things to note here:

### Deleted results of localedef

Manually created results of `localedef` are really always deleted, simply because `locale-gen` [is a script](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2019-February/296389.html) doing so:

```
if [ -z "$1" ] && [ -z "$KEEP" ]; then
        # Remove all old locale dir and locale-archive before generating new
        # locale data.
        rm -rf /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive || true
        for dir in /usr/lib/locale/*; do
                [ -e "$dir" ] || continue
                if [ "${dir#/usr/lib/locale/}" = C.UTF-8 ]; then
                        # owned by libc-bin
                        continue
                fi
                rm -rf "$dir" 2>/dev/null || true
        done
fi
```

To circumvent this, one really needs to make the locale available differently, so that it gets generated always when locales are generated at all.

### /usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED

That file IS in fact the correct way to make my locale available and how I added it IS correct. The line `de_DE.CP1252 CP1252` results in the same locale being created using `dpkg-reconfigure locales` like using `localedef` manually. The only difference is that in the first case the locale is added to the file `/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive`, while the latter creates individual directories. That difference leads to the following problem...

### Postgres not recognizing changes

I simply never restarted Postgres during my tests after executing `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and that is necessary!

When the individual directories created using `localedef` where removed or added, Postgres recognized that instantly whenever a session to a database using that locale has been created. That's why I thought locales are always read as needed, which doesn't seem to be the case. Instead I guess the archive file is only opened once per process and only if some locale is not found in there, the additional directories are recognized and that on-demand. So when the archive file has been deleted and created newly, Postgres simply didn't recognized and still worked with the old contents, which didn't ever contain my locale.

After restarting Postgres that used the new archive file with my locale embedded and things worked again. This can easily be reproduced by running `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to remove my locale again and without a restart of Postgres it simply continues to work. After a restart it fails again until the locale gets added to the archive file again.

### Do not use localedef?

So it seems the correct approach to make results of `localedef` survive `dpkg-reconfigure locales` in the end is to NOT use `localedef` manually, but instead define the needed locale in the file `/usr/local/share/i18n/SUPPORTED` and in the worst case to restart the system.